# Есть ли вариант в Golang отработать типы через interface{}?

Tags: golang, интерфейс, типы

Можно ли как-то в Го операцию сложения сделать одной строкой без определения типа? Понимаю, что нужно a.(uint64) + b.(uint64) указывать, но вдруг есть способ автоопределения типа?

```
func f (a interface{}, b interface{}) interface{} {
    return a + b
}

a := uint64(100)
b := float64(200)
c := f (a, b)
```

Comment: И какой конкретно тип переменной `c` по-вашему должен автоопределиться?

Comment: Допускаю создание определённого типа, например float64

Comment: неа. такого нет

Answer (score 1):

ответ не простой.

в версиях Го до 1.18 нужно кастить в тип данных, что не очень. А вот с 1.18 версии появляются дженерики. Уже вышла версия [go1.18rc1](https://go.dev/dl/#go1.18rc1)

Определяем функицю, параметризованную T, используя [constraint](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#constraints) для ограничения типов у T

```
import "constraints"

type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}

func add[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a + b
}
```

получается, что

- `Number` - наш тип, аля множество `constraints.Integer` и `constraints.Float`
- `constraints.Integer` - просто целочисленные типы данных
- `contraints.Float` - с плавающей точкой

Это позволит нам вызывать `add` с любыми двумя аргументами Number типа. Тогда в теле функции мы сможем использовать любую операцию, которая поддерживается всеми типами. Например, умножение, как в вашем примере

```
func multiply[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a * b
}
```

Конечно, тут тоже есть ограничение: аргументы должны иметь один и тот же тип. Независимо от дженериков, вы не можете использовать разные типы. вот из спецификаций [Operators](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Operators):

> [...] the operand types must be identical unless the operation
> involves shifts or untyped constants.

то есть следующий пример не будет работать

```
add(2.5, 2)
```

потому что компилятор определит тип `T` из первого аргумента `2.5`, который по умолчанию равен `float64`, а затем не сможет сопоставить тип `2`, который по умолчанию равен `int`.

```
package main

import (
    "constraints"
    "fmt"
)

type Number interface {
    constraints.Integer | constraints.Float
}

func main() {
    a := 1
    b := 2
    
    fmt.Println(add(1, 2))     // 3
    fmt.Println(add(a, b))     // 3
    fmt.Println(add(1.5, 3.2)) // 4.7
}

func add[T Number](a, b T) T {
    return a + b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, в Go такого нет - это не динамический язык..

Можно либо определять тип и приводить его к желаемому через reflection, либо ждать Go 1.18 и реализовать вашу функцию через generic-ки.